# Mergesort Criticism in C

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

I have written a merge sort in C and would like any advice on how to improve it. Any advice helps to make the code better!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

static void mergesort_helper(void *array, uint32_t index, uint32_t length, size_t size_element, int32_t compare(void *, void *), void *storage)
{
   uint32_t i, j, k;
   if(length == 1)
   {
      /*printf("\n%d, %d\n", index, length);*/
      return;
   }

   mergesort_helper(array, index, length / 2, size_element, compare, storage);

   if(length % 2 == 0)
      mergesort_helper(array, (index + (index + length)) / 2, length / 2, size_element, compare, storage);
   else
      mergesort_helper(array, (index + (index + length)) / 2, length / 2 + 1, size_element, compare, storage);

   /*sorting part*/
   i = index;
   j = (index + (index + length)) / 2;
   k = 0;
   while(i < (index + (index + length)) / 2 || j < (index + length))
   {
      if(i < (index + (index + length)) / 2 && (compare(array + i * size_element, array + j * size_element) <= 0 || j >= (index + length)))
      {
          memcpy(storage + k * size_element, array + i * size_element, size_element);
          i++;
      }
      else if(j < (index + length) && (compare(array + i * size_element, array + j * size_element) > 0) || i >= (index + (index + length)) / 2)
      {
          memcpy(storage + k * size_element, array + j * size_element, size_element);
          j++;
      }
      k++;
   }
   memcpy(array + index * size_element, storage, length * size_element);
}

/*
   array -  to be sorted
   length - exclusive
   size_element - how big is one element
*/
void mergesort(void *array, uint32_t length, size_t size_element, int32_t compare(void *, void *))
{
   void *storage;
   if(length == 0)
      return;

   storage = malloc(size_element * length);
   mergesort_helper(array, 0, length, size_element, compare, storage);
   free(storage);
}


/*user code*/
int32_t compare(void *ptr1, void *ptr2)
{
   int32_t *temp_ptr1, *temp_ptr2;
   temp_ptr1 = (int32_t *)ptr1;
   temp_ptr2 = (int32_t *)ptr2;

   if(*temp_ptr1 < *temp_ptr2)
      return -1;
   else if(*temp_ptr1 > *temp_ptr2)
      return 1;

   return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
   uint32_t i;
   int32_t array[] = {6, 4, 3, 2, 7, -100, 1, 0, 5, 8, -100, 8};

   for(i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); i++)
   {
      printf("%d ", array[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");

   mergesort(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]), sizeof(array[0]), &compare);

   for(i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); i++)
   {
      printf("%d ", array[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Merge sort makes little sense for random-access arrays.

Comment: What would you recommend that I use for sorting a random-access arrays?

Comment: If this isn't homework, you must know about the `qsort` function which is already in the standard C library. Your `mergesort` function has almost identical conventions to `qsort` (except for the missing `const` on the comparison function's parameters) which is probably no coincidence.  The only drawback of `qsort` is that it's not required to be a stable sort.

Comment: @Kaz Another drawback is that it's generic. If you *know* the type, you can do your comparisons and assignments directly instead of needing to call `cmp` and `memmove`, at which point it's fairly easy to write a merge sort that'll beat `qsort` by a decent margin. (Although a handwritten quicksort with random pivot would presumably do even better, on average.)

Comment: @Kaz In the GLibc qsort() is actually implemented as mergesort because it performs better than quicksort. Therefore it makes sense to implement mergesort for associative arrays. Moreover quicksort is not stable which sucks for any interactive use, such as in a GUI.

Comment: Don't mix C++ concepts with C one major code smell, others mentioned by G. Sliepen. The code will compile but its hybrid C and C++

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Avoid code duplication

Your code is more verbose than necessary, because you are repeating a lot of things unnecessarily, or write things in a more complex way than necessary. For example:

```
(index + (index + length)) / 2
```

This looks really weird, and is actually equivalent to:

```
index + length / 2
```

Which makes much more sense. Even with that change, that expression is used a lot in the code, so it's best to give it a name:

```
uint32_t middle = index + length / 2;
```

You also duplicated a call to `mergesort_helper()` in order to handle odd and even cases of `length`. However, you don't have to if you write it like so:

```
uint32_t middle = index + length / 2;
uint32_t end = index + length;

mergesort_helper(array, index, middle - index, size_element, compare, storage);
mergesort_helper(array, middle, end - middle, size_element, compare, storage);
```

You might also want to consider renaming `index` to `start`.

## Use `const` for pointer arguments in `compare()`

Since the function `compare()` should not modify the elements it is comparing, the arguments should be pointers to `const`:

```
int32_t compare(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2) {
   const int32_t *temp_ptr1 = ptr1;
   const int32_t *temp_ptr2 = ptr2;
   ...
}
```

## Optimizing the `while`-loop

There are a few minor changes that can be made to speed up the `while`-loop a little bit. First, calling `compare()` is probably going to be the most expensive operation, so you would want to avoid calling it if possible. Rearrange the order in which you check things to make use of [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
if(i < middle && (j >= end || compare(...)))
```

In the above, `compare()` will only be called if `i < middle` is `true` and `j >= end` is `false`.

Another possible optimization is realizing that if `i >= middle || j >= end`, you know you only need to copy the remainder of one side of the midpoint. Instead of doing that element by element, you could do that in one large `memcpy()`. It also simplifies the `if`-statements in the `while`-loop, like so:

```
while (i < middle && j < end) {
    if (compare(array + i * size_element, array + j * size_element) <= 0) {
        memcpy(storage + k * size_element, array + i * size_element, size_element);
        i++;
    } else {
        memcpy(storage + k * size_element, array + j * size_element, size_element);
        j++;
    }

    k++;
}

/* Copy the remainder */
if (i < middle) {
    memcpy(storage + k * size_element, array + i * size_element, size_element * (middle - i));
} else {
    memcpy(storage + k * size_element, array + j * size_element, size_element * (end - j));
}
```

The above has also the advantage that `compare()` is only called once every iteration, whereas in your original code it could have been called twice.

## Avoid `void` pointer arithmetic

Lau G mentioned void pointers, and indeed doing [arithmetic on `void` pointers is illegal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c). The simple workaround is to cast it to a `char *` first:

```
static void mergesort_helper(void *array_ptr, ...)
{
    char *array = array_ptr;
    ...
```

To catch these sort of issues, enable strict compiler warnings. For GCC and Clang, use `-Wall -pedantic`. Fix all the warnings the compiler produces.

Comment: Any reason not to use `const void * const` type arguments to compare()?

Comment: @spuck The only argument I can think of to not use that would be that adding `const` to everything makes the code more verbose. The chance of accidentily changing the pointer itself is small, and making the address `const` does not help the compiler produce better code, whereas making the value pointed to `const` does allow better code to be generated and it protects the caller from mistakes inside `compare()`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen More to the point, it doesn't matter if it changes the pointer itself, since that copy of the pointer is local to `compare`. Changing the local copy will not change the copy in `mergesort_helper`. Whereas changing the value it points to would.

Answer (score 4):

## Interface

A more appropriate type for `length` would be `size_t`.  And I'd expect the `compare` argument to be a function returning plain `int`, and accepting pointers to `const void`.

## Test program

The test program could be improved with the addition of a `is_sorted()` function to confirm the result and return the appropriate success/failure value.  I would recommend saving the repeated calculation of array length into a variable:

```
const size_t length = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];
```

I suggest reducing the scope of `i` to just the loops:

```
for (size_t i = 0;  i < length;  ++i)
```

## Comparator

We don't need to declare and assign separately, and we don't need to write a cast to convert from `void*`:

> ```
>    int32_t *temp_ptr1, *temp_ptr2;
>    temp_ptr1 = (int32_t *)ptr1;
>    temp_ptr2 = (int32_t *)ptr2;
> ```

I would write that as:

```
   int32_t const *a = ptr1;
   int32_t const *b = ptr2;
```

I took the liberty to use shorter and more distinct names, which are easier to tell apart where they are used.

There's a well-known trick for returning -1, 0 or +1 from comparisons, relying on the fact that boolean values are 0 and 1:

```
   return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);
```

## Helper function

Again, reduce the scope of variables, and declare them where they are assigned, to reduce chance of using uninitialised values.

We have a repeated calculation of `(index + (index + length)) / 2`.  Not only could this be given a name, but we can remove the error caused when the sum is large enough to overflow:

```
const size_t mid_index = index + length / 2;
```

We have a lot of invalid pointer arithmetic such as `array + i * size_element`.  Because `array` is pointer to void, addition is not defined - we probably want to change the argument's type to `char*`.  Similarly, `storage` should also be `char*`.

## Sort function

We allocate memory, but blindly continue when `malloc()` returns a null pointer, leading to Undefined Behaviour.  Don't do that!

Comment: If in the interface you saw "void const *ptr" instead of "const void *ptr" would that also be fine as both produce the same result of the data being const right? Which syntax do you recommend?

Comment: Either is fine - but try to stay consistent!  FWIW, the C Standard writes `const` first.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too confident with my knowledge on (void) pointers so I will avoid giving feedback on the pointer related stuff.

### Unnecessary if...else statement.

```c
if(length % 2 == 0)
    mergesort_helper(array, (index + (index + length)) / 2, length / 2, size_element, compare, storage);
else
    mergesort_helper(array, (index + (index + length)) / 2, length / 2 + 1, size_element, compare, storage);
```

Can be turned into:

```c
mergesort_helper(array, (index + (index + length)) / 2, length / 2 + (length % 2), size_element, compare, storage);
```

### Minor improvement to the length check in `mergesort`.

When the array is of length 1 it is possible to return early as well, because an array of length 1 is already sorted.

```c
void mergesort(void *array, const uint32_t length, const size_t size_element, int32_t compare(void *, void *))
{
    ...
    if (length <= 1) { return; }
    ...
}
```

### Use const

`length` and `size_element` don't change in the `mergesort` and `mergesort_helper` functions. This is also the case for `index` in the `mergesort_helper` function. It would be best to use the const keyword to indicate this, this can also be helpful to the compiler.

```c
void mergesort(void *array, const uint32_t length, const size_t size_element, int32_t compare(int32_t *, int32_t *))
static void mergesort_helper(void *array, const uint32_t index, const uint32_t length, const size_t size_element, int32_t compare(int32_t *, int32_t *), void *storage)
```

### Styling & Readability

Some of these are opinionated so you can use what you see fit.

- Use an indentation of 4 spaces instead of 3.
- Use a space between `if/while/for` and `(`
- Use brackets on if...else statements even if they are one line. There's a chance more lines will be added to the if...else statement later on. Forgetting to add brackets when this happens can lead to bugs that could have been avoided if brackets where added from the start.
- Merge sort consists of two words so `merge_sort` would be more appropriate.
- `(index + (index + length)) / 2` represents the middle index it would make the code easier to read if it was assigned to a const variable.

```c
static void mergesort_helper(void *array, const uint32_t index, const uint32_t length, const size_t size_element, int32_t compare(void *, void *), void *storage)
{
    uint32_t i, j, k;
    if (length == 1)
    {
        /*printf("\n%d, %d\n", index, length);*/
        return;
    }

    const uint32_t m_index = (index + (index + length)) / 2;

    mergesort_helper(array, index, length / 2, size_element, compare, storage);

    mergesort_helper(array, m_index, length / 2 + length % 2, size_element, compare, storage);

    /*sorting part*/
    i = index;
    j = m_index;
    k = 0;

    while (i < m_index || j < (index + length))
    {
        if (i < m_index && (compare(array + i * size_element, array + j * size_element) <= 0 || j >= (index + length)))
        {
            memcpy(storage + k * size_element, array + i * size_element, size_element);
            i++;
        }
        else if (j < (index + length) && (compare(array + i * size_element, array + j * size_element)> 0 || i >= m_index))
        {
            memcpy(storage + k * size_element, array + j * size_element, size_element);
            j++;
        }

        k++;
    }

    memcpy(array + index * size_element, storage, length * size_element);
}
```

Maybe it is possible to make the if..else statement in the while loop of mergesort_helper more clean. If it is 100% certain either the `if` or `if else` is true, it would be possible to just make the `if else` statement an `else` statement.

Answer (score 3):

1. Keep your includes ordered for maintainability and shorter diffs.
   The separate sorted groups should be in order: This files header (first to ensure it remains self-contained), external libraries (standard and additional), this project's headers.

   ```
   #include <assert.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>
   ```
2. There are many ways to represent an array-slice, but fundamentally you only need a pointer to the first element, and the count. The first element of the underlying array, if you even know it, is of no interest at all.
3. If the only way to get to some memory is by a function-argument, marking that [`restrict`](//en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) allows better optimization and is good documentation.
4. Instead of special-casing remainder / no remainder when determining half the count, just subtract the range handled from the whole. It's less error-prone.
5. Your code for merging is over-complicated because you don't handle all the rest at once when one of the sorted sequences runs empty. That's also inefficient.
6. You only need half the scratch-space if you move the left sequence out before merging to the destination, instead of merging in the scratch-space and copying the result back.
7. There is a type in C dedicated for object-size and thus also array-indices: `size_t`.
   Use it where appropriate.
8. `void*`-arithmetic (assuming `sizeof(void) == 1`) is a gcc extension. There is no reason to use it as you could just use a `char*` instead and be strictly conformant.
9. Comparison-functions in C traditionally return `int`, the significance being smaller, equal, or bigger to zero. So, why would you ever consider anything else?
10. If a function should not modify arguments passed by pointer, let the type reflect it. Const-correctness allows the compiler to help catch errors.
11. Consider adding a typedef to avoid repeating the comparator's type.
12. Even though zero is an invalid input for `mergesort_helper()`, I personally think reasoning is easier if the guard-clause reads `< 2` than `== 1`.
13. Avoid overly long lines. Horizontal scrolling kills readability and thus maintainability.
14. While mixing declarations and statements is strictly speaking not allowed before C99, everybody already implemented it already because it is so useful.

    Defer declaring a variable until you have the proper value to initialize it to. Don't initialize it to some arbitrary value, and don't leave it uninitialized if you can help it. That avoids errors and makes eases understanding.

```
typedef int (*comparator)(const void*, const void*);

static void mergesort_helper(
    char* restrict p,
    size_t n,
    size_t s,
    comparator f,
    char* restrict scratch
) {
    if (n < 2) return;
    const size_t mid = n / 2;
    mergesort_helper(p, mid, s, f, scratch);
    mergesort_helper(p + mid * s, n - mid, s, f, scratch);
    memcpy(scratch, p, mid * s);
    char *aa = scratch, *ab = scratch + mid * s, *ba = p + mid * s, *bb = p + n * s;
    while (aa != ab && ba != bb) {
        char** x = f(aa, ba) <= 0 ? &aa : &ba;
        memcpy(p, *x, s);
        p += s;
        *x += s;
    }
    memcpy(p, aa, ab - aa);
}
```

15. While immediately returning if no elements should be sorted is enough to preserve the invariants of your code, I would also do so for a single element. That is, if I optimized for the trivial case at all, which is a pessimization of the far more important common case. Thanks to changing the guard-clause in `mergesort_helper()` and thus its invariants, doing so is no longer needed.
16. You really should handle insufficient memory, if only by calling `abort()`.
17. As `mergesort()` is the entry-point, I would set a few `assert()`s for sanity-testing during development.

```
/*
    p   - array to be sorted
    n   - number of elements
    s   - size of each element
    f   - comparator
*/
void mergesort(void * restrict p, size_t n, size_t s, comparator f) {
    assert(s && n <= (size_t)-1 / s && (!n || (f && p)));
    void* scratch = malloc(n / 2 * s);
    if (!scratch && n / 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed for mergesort().\n");
        abort();
    }
    mergesort_helper(p, n, s, f, scratch);
    free(scratch);
}
```

18. There is a simpler idiomatic way to define three-way-comparison even if simply subtracting doesn't fit.
19. Do not cast from or to `void*`. Implicit conversions work and are less error-prone.

```
static int compare(const void* pa, const void* pb) {
    const int32_t *a = pa, *b = pb;
    return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);
}
```

20. You have exactly one test-case, and that for the typical case. Automate it (by adding a corresponding `is_sorted()` tester), and try with one and zero elements to at least test the obvious corner cases.
21. Using the wrong format-specifier for [`printf`](//en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is a bug.
22. `return 0;` is implicit for `main()` since C99.
23. Return an error if your program ends with a detected failure.

```
int is_sorted(const void * restrict p, size_t n, size_t s, comparator f) {
    assert(s && n <= (size_t)-1 / s && (!n || (f && p)));
    if (n--)
        for (const char* q = p; n--; q += s)
            if (f(q, q + s) > 0)
                return 0;
    return 1;
}

static int test(int32_t array[], size_t n) {
    printf("%zu: ", n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%" PRId32 " ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    mergesort(array, n, sizeof *array, &compare);

    int res = is_sorted(array, n, sizeof *array, &compare);

    printf(res ? "OK: " : "FAIL: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%" PRId32 " ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return res;
}

int main() {
    int32_t array[] = {6, 4, 3, 2, 7, -100, 1, 0, 5, 8, -100, 8};

    return !test(array, sizeof array / sizeof *array)
        || !test(array, 1)
        || !test(array, 0)
        || !test(0, 0);
}
```

See it all coming together [live on coliru](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1928def9a3cec5a).

Comment: Your code contains a LOT of one-letter variables. Some are OK (like `n` and `i`, and `a` and `b` in the comparison function), but I would recommend giving them better names so it is clear what they stand for.

Comment: Is it okay to use asserts in "real code" or should those be avoided when not testing the program?

Comment: Do you mean in a release? There it will be compiled to nothing. In a debug build? There it should fire. Both are "real code".

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: in order to improve performance while keeping it simple, switch to insertion sort for small arrays.

Congratulations on choosing mergesort! This is a great choice. It is very elegant, stable and can achieve great performance without the code turning in an horrible mess as is typically the case with quicksort.

There are many answers already so I will chose a different angle.

I do not know what kind of improvement you are looking for, but if performance is a concern, the cost of recursion is going to be prohibitive for small (sub-)arrays.

One good way to fix this is to test for the size of the array and use insertion sort instead if the number of entries is below a limit. Start with a limit of 8 and then try other values later if you are into performance tuning.

You could alternatively write a non-recursive version of mergesort. All you would achieve is that the code would be less readable, though. Don't do it! And insertion sorts makes fewer comparisons than merge sort on smalls arrays anyway.

Another more complex way would be to investigate timsort. Timsort is the state of the art of adaptative merge algorithms nowadays. Many language runtimes implement the standard sorting algorithm as timsort. The complexity of the code increase greatly, though.

Finally, if you enjoy experimentation, here is a last idea. You could figure out that internal sorts only exist nowadays in the special case where the array is small enough to fit in the CPU's level 1 cache. In all other cases, what you are doing is actually an external sort. And guess which algorithm shines particularly for this purpose? Yes, right, it is indeed mergesort! Thus you could try to implement a cache-aware k-way mergesort or a cache-aware timsort. This would some extra layers of complexity as you would need to write some architecture-dependent code. But who knows what results such an experiment would yield?

Another way to improve performance for large item sizes could be to check for the size of elements and apply mergesort to an array of pointers to the elements instead of the array of elements itself. As I recall, the implementation of qsort() in glibc does this.

Anyway, these are only a few ideas from the top of my head. Do what suits you best and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Create simple code for simple tasks don't overcomplicate it, and better name your functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
void merge (int *a, int n, int m) {
    int i, j, k;
    int *x = malloc(n * sizeof (int));
    for (i = 0, j = m, k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        x[k] = j == n      ? a[i++]
             : i == m      ? a[j++]
             : a[j] < a[i] ? a[j++]
             :               a[i++];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = x[i];
    }
    free(x);
}
 
void merge_sort (int *a, int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    int m = n / 2;
    merge_sort(a, m);
    merge_sort(a + m, n - m);
    merge(a, n, m);
}
```

Reference code http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#C